# issues while npx install

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am trying to execute

```
npx playwright install`
```

i have placed this node-v18.17.0-linux-x64 at this location

```
/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v18.17.0-linux-x64
```

but getting this error

```
bash: npx: command not found...
Failed to search for file: cannot update repo 'rpm.releases.hashicorp.com_RHEL_hashicorp.rep': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried; Last error: Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for https://rpm.releases.hashicorp.com/RHEL/hashicorp.rep/repodata/repomd.xml [Could not resolve host: rpm.releases.hashicorp.com]
```

after running

```
npx playwright install
```

what else i am missing here??

```
OS details:
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.6 (Ootpa)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.6"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.6 (Ootpa)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8::baseos"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://access.redhat.com/documentation/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.6
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6"
```

to execute this command successfully.
npx playwright install
added all the dependencies earlier

Comment: How did you install node.js itself? I guess there is a problem with PATH or shell configuration, you may try using nvm

Comment: nvm and [fnm](https://github.com/Schniz/fnm) are broadly used. The latter is faster too

Comment: export PATH=/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v18.17.1-linux-x64/bin:$PATH this is the path i have defined.

Comment: is there any dependencies I am missing?